# Mac arm, universal library, how to ling against 2 openssl libs?

Tags: cmake, arm, intel, apple-m1, universal

So my understanding is that on mac if I want to build universal library or executable I need to do :

```
set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES "arm64;x86_64" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
```

Now this is great, but if say, this project needs to link against brew - openSSL or vcpkg - zlib...
Then I need to somehow link against 2 openSSL versions?
Since vcpkg builds for either arm or intel, I have now 2x vcpkg installed, 1 for each architecture.
I also have 2x brew installed for each architecture.

So my question is...
How can I

```
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED ${BREW_INTEL})
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED ${BREW_ARM})
find_package(zlib REQUIRED ${vcpkg_INTEL})
find_package(zlib REQUIRED ${vcpkg_ARM})
```

So that each Architecture targets correct sub library... version ?

Am I wrong with this? Right? how do I bite it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Lacking a better option, I've used `lipo` to build a multiplatform library:

```
lipo /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1o/lib/libssl.a \
     /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.a \
     -create -output ~/lib_all/libssl.a
```

Comment: Yea I was gonna do that too, then I realized that opeimageio uses like 10 other libraries and and suddently its a massive task to universal-up-everything else... So I went with 2 package managers each & if/else in my cmake. Just though that there was maybe a better way & so I posted here.

Comment: @Dariusz: Please make that an answer (with enough details to reproduce).
We need sometimes bad answers to lure in the good answers.

Comment: Hahaha good one :D Ok will do